# what are all mandatory JAVA jars have to use for IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

am new to IBM MQ, currently am using com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allClient jar. now am facing error as mentioned below:

`java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:Java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider:com.ibm.mq.jmqi.CustomCharsetProvider not a subtype`

Comment: It would be useful if you could post the full call stack of the exception. What version of com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar are you using? Googling for the above exception shows multiple hits.

Comment: This error is likely because in addition to the `com.ibm.allclient.jar` you have some older `com.ibm*.jar` files in your CLASSPATH.   Check and remove them and it should clear up the error.